# [VBA]How to delete all useless 0 in the end of a column

Tags: vba

My purpose needs to find out the time gap between every row.  It should go 1 second by 1 second, but you will see until 11:40, there is a large one. For example, the time A3-A2=B1. I solved this problem already, my code is the following.

It runs OK, but in end of column B, there is a long list of 00:00:00. I want to match the last number of column B with column A, that means column B and A should have the same length. Thousands of 00:00:00 in the end.

```
Sub CalculateTimeGap()  

Columns("B:B").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Range("A1").Value = "Time"

Columns("A:A").NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
Columns("B:B").Formula = "=A2-A1"
Range("B1").Value = "Time Difference(s)"
Columns("B:B").NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"

lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
End Sub


Time      Time Difference(s)
11:28:37    00:00:01
11:28:38    00:00:01
11:28:39    00:00:01
11:28:40    00:11:35
11:40:15    00:00:01
11:40:16    00:00:01
11:40:17    00:00:01
11:40:18    00:00:01
            00:00:00
            00:00:00
            00:00:00
            00:00:00
            00:00:00
            00:00:00
            00:00:00
            00:00:00
            00:00:00
            00:00:00
```

I tried to add code inside to delete the 00:00:00 but it didn't work.

```
If Range("B").Value = "00:00:00" Then
    'Range("B").Value.Delete
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I think It would be better to use a loop in here

```
 dim LR,i as double
     LR=application.count(range("A:A"))
    for i=1 to lr step 1
     cells(i,2).value=cells(i+1,1).value-cells(i,1).value
    next i
```

and alternative to preserve you code would be:

```
Sub CalculateTimeGap()  

Columns("B:B").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Range("A1").Value = "Time"
 dim LR as variant
 LR=application.count(range("A:A"))
Columns("A:A").NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
Columns("B2:B"&LR).Formula = "=A2-A1"
Range("B1").Value = "Time Difference(s)"
Columns("B:B").NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"

lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a formula in column B instead of using VBA

assuming the table in your example to be at A1, put `=IF(ISBLANK(A3),"",A3-A2)` in B2 and copy down as far down as you like